# SPImport Error: An event receiver has canceled the request

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, powershell

im running below Powershell Import CMD to import a site

import-spweb "URL"   -Path "E:\" -updateVersions Overwrite -includeusersecurity -nofilecompression -Force

and this gets below error .......

> Error: An event receiver has canceled the request. [4/10/2013 6:34:35
>   PM] [Folder] [Projects]   Debug:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateFileOrFolderProperties(String
>   bstrWebUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varProperties, Int32
>   fMigrationSemantics, Int32 fReGhost, Byte& piLevel)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.UpdateOnImport()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply. it was a problem with 1 of the subsites that has the custom object.

so i had to export the only subsite XX
delete Subsite XX for the source
export the site (without subsite XX)
import the subsite XX

don't know how but it's workfor me ..

Txn.

Answer (score 0):

Either disable event firing or disable the event receiver in picture.

Comment: Can you please extend this answer to make it more useful? Some code examples, other resources?